# String formatting in python isn't working as expected

Tags: python, string

I'm building a string via the following:

```
pagination +='<li>''<a href="/main/?page=%(current_link)s'+link+'">%(current)s</a></li>' % \
                     {'current_link': current_link, 'current': current_link}
```

When viewing the page in the browser, the text shows up fine but the link points to "..%(current_link)s...". I've tried naming both of them 'current_link' in the string itself but that didn't work so I tried the approach above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have separated the string, making the `%` operator only work on the last part.

Try it like this:

```
pagination +='<li><a href="/main/?page=%(current_link)s>%(current)s</a></li>' % \
                     {'current_link': current_link, 'current': current_link}
```

Or if you intended the `link` variable in there like so:

```
pagination +='<li><a href="/main/?page=%(current_link)s%(link)s>%(current)s</a></li>' % \
                     {'link': link, 'current_link': current_link, 'current': current_link}
```

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try that. How did you get the HTML to show up in the question though? I was about to delete the question because I couldn't get it to show up

Comment: @user1100778, if you start a line with four spaces it will show up as code. Read here for other formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Okay I tried it out and it works great and makes sense. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @user1100778, you can mark the question as solved if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hm. You are mixing concatenation with `+` and formatting with `%`, and I think, this is a matter of operator precedence: `%` binds stronger than `+`, so

```
("%(a)s" + "%(b)s" % { 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B' }) == '%(a)sB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine cramming strings together with no operator (`'foo''bar'`), concatenating with `+`, and formatting with `%`.  You're only formatting the final string.